# COMO PUEDO INSERTAR UN DIV EN MÁS DE UNA FILA BOOTSTRAP RESPONSIVE?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

Surgió un problema en donde quería que hubiera un `aside` que abarcara desde la fila inicial hasta la final pero a la hora de poner los grid responsive como el .col-sm se deforma el sitio.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center ">
            <div class=" col-9 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
                <div class="row  ">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
                        <p>CONTENIDO</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-success">
                        <p>CON 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4  bg-primary">
                        <p>CON 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4  bg-secondary">
                        <p>CON 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <aside class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 bg-success">
                <p>lorem</p>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask], te comento que esta no es la forma de exponer posibles soluciones, justo primero expones la pregunta con la duda y lo que has tratado y posterior debajo en la zona de respuestas colocas a detalle la solución amigo, de paso te invito a realizar el [tour]

Comment: Diego, no malinterpretes los votos negativos. La intención es excelente, la ejecución no tanto.

Comment: Tal vez si redactas una pregunta específica sobre el asunto y te auto respondes, sería mejor recibido tu aporte. Pero colocar en el ***área de preguntas*** un aporte que no es una pregunta, no es bien recibido por la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

mi pequeño aporte espero sea util.Se trata de extender un div por mas de una fila, logrando al final que sea responsive.Dentro de una fila ya creada,crear un div con la longitud de columna deseada para nuestros elementos laterales, asi limitando a cierto numero las columnas de este div ,ya fuera de este div pondremos nuestro elemento a expandirse

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center ">
        <div class="bg-danger col-12">
            <p>HEADER</p>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-9 bg-danger">
            <div class="row  ">
                <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
                    <p>CONTENIDO</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-success">
                    <p>CON 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4  bg-primary">
                    <p>CON 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4  bg-secondary">
                    <p>CON 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <aside class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 bg-success">
            <p>lorem</p>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```